# does not match prepared variables

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\New\test.php on line 11

Line 11 contains this
`$stmt->bind_param('ss', $pageid, $pagename);`

Here is the PHP code it's referring to

```
$pageid = 7;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT pageid, pagename FROM pages WHERE pageid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $pageid, $pagename);
$stmt->bind_result($pageid, $pagename);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

while ($stmt->fetch()):?>

<div class="post" id="post">
<div class="post_title"><h2><?php echo $pageid ?></h2></div>
<p><?php echo  $pagename ?></p></div>

<?php endwhile ?>

<?php 
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

`$stmt->bind_param('s', $pageid);`